# Sending Fax with python?

Tags: python, fax

Ok, we aren't in the mid-1980s any more, but anyway. Are there any [fax](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fax) libraries for python?

Comment: Using a modem attached to the server, or through an external Gateway? On what kind of platform? In which country?

Comment: Country would be in Eurozone. No other constraints.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have no experience with it, but I guess you're looking for something like [hylafax](http://www.hylafax.org/archive/2005-12/msg00120.php), right?  A post [here](http://www.hylafax.org/archive/2005-12/msg00120.php) purports to show how to use it from Python (haven't tried myself).

Comment: Thank you for the link – since I have no experience with fax+python, it provides me with some starting points.

Answer (score 2):

> Country would be in Eurozone. No other constraints.

There are companies which offer email-to-fax and fax-to-email conversion (so you can send/receive faxes by sending and receiving emails).

Answer (score 2):

Check out the link for a number of code samples demonstrating how to [fax with Python](http://www.interfax.net/en/dev/python) using a commercial internet fax service.

As an example, the simplest one requires just this:

```
from interfax import client

print 'Testing SendCharFax...'
c = client.InterFaxClient('USERNAME','PASSWORD')
result = c.sendCharFax('+12125554874', 'This is a test')
print '   Char Fax was sent with result code: %d' % result
```

Answer (score 1):

dynaptico-pamfax is an open source Python module to send faxes using PamFax:

https://github.com/dynaptico/pamfaxp

The module is licensed under a MIT license. It can be installed with pip:

pip install dynaptico-pamfax

Additional information is available from:

http://www.pamfax.biz/en/developers/introduction/

Answer (score 1):

You can also use phaxio for this purpose

details can be found at

http://www.phaxio.com/

https://github.com/setaris/pyphaxio

Answer (score 0):

The one I found by google for sending faxes is python-faxage. This can found at:
[Internet client for sending and receiving faxes.](https://code.google.com/p/python-faxage/)

EDIT

above mentioned link is now dead, you can see the following package instead:
http://www.phaxio.com/